# Can not create project and debugging code on visual code

Tags: visual-studio

I has just installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2022. But I can not create file in project, as a result Start debugging is disable.
How can I debug code in this case.

[image]

Comment: You have not created a project, you have only created a file. Use the "new project" wizard.

Comment: @PMF thanks your answer. However, when I installed VS, I can not create "new project". do you you know anyway to fix it in details?

Comment: Are you saying that the menu option "File->New->Project" does not exist?